# Refresh fragment on back from activity (actionBar)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I'm facing problem with fragment reload when back from activity. Let me show how I do this now. I'm using support lib v4 and v7, my main activity is

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;    

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    Tab tab = actionBar
            .newTab()
            .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setTabListener(
                    new TabListener<MyFragment>(this, "myfragment",
                            MyFragment.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);
```

fragments are created like here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs
another part of MainActivity

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.item:
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

fragment used in actionBar tab

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

private ListAdapter myListAdapter;
private ListView listView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

and finally SecondActivity

```
 public class SecondActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private EditText nameET;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.done:

        if (saveProfile()) {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        } else {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

part of manifest

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.package.SecondActivity"
        android:icon="@drawable/second"
        android:label="@string/second"
        android:parentActivityName="com.package.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >

        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support API level 7+ -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.package.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

When I'm in SecondActivity and tap back or my action MainActivity.onCreate is called, when I use android:launchMode="singleTop" for MainActivity after back it is still on right tab but no idea how to refresh. I saw many topic here on stackoverflow but no solution so far

Comment: You don't say how you are creating the fragment now. I'm guessing that you create it somewhere, but when you return from second activity, it is not recreated. I would suggest saving instance state in the Activity.onSaveInstanceState and then recreate the fragment in the Activity.onCreate, if saved instance state says fragment should be recreated.

Comment: I'm using code from here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs

Comment: But when I use android:launchMode="singleTop" on create is not invoked,and this is only way i know to get last tab after back from SecondActivity

Comment: you also have Activity.onRestoreInstanceState() and Activity.onResume()